# How can i change the dimensions of this grid using canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following coordinate grid:jsfiddle.net/b6pwrrca/29

how can I change the dimensions so that the x-axis runs from -7 to 7, for example, and the y-axis runs from -5 to 12?

I posted the code that I believe is relevant below:

```
function start(){
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#888';
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "dark gray";
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
for(var i=1;i<size;i++){
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/size/2*i, 0);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/size/2*i, canvas.height);
ctx.fillText("- "+        (sizei),canvas.width/size/2*i,canvas.height/50*30
);
    ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2 + canvas.width/size/2*i, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2 + canvas.width/size/2*i, canvas.height);
ctx.fillText("+ "+i,canvas.width/2 +     canvas.width/size/2*i,canvas.height/50*24);
}
    for(var i=1;i<size;i++){
ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height/size/2*i);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/size/2*i);
ctx.fillText("+ "+(size-    i),canvas.width/50*27,canvas.height/size/2*i);
ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height/2 + canvas.height/size/2*i);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2 + canvas.height/size/2*i);
ctx.fillText("- "+i,canvas.width/50*27,canvas.height/2 + canvas.height/size/2*i);
}
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.moveTo(canvas.width/2, 0);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width/2, canvas.height);
ctx.moveTo(0, canvas.height/2);
ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();



    for(var i=0;i<dots.length;i++){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
var xc = canvas.width/2 + canvas.width/2/size*dots[i][0];
var yc = canvas.height/2 + canvas.height/2/size*(0-dots[i][1]);
ctx.arc(xc,yc,10,0,2*Math.PI);



ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
 }

}
window.onload = start();
```

Comment: Your code appears to be homework. You might want to try to solve the problem yourself as a learning experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question & answer is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @markE it isn't homework...that was hours of effort on my part as a complete beginner to modify preexisting examples to get to that point. You might want to try knowing what you're talking about before making negative assumptions about people. (I'm not even affiliated with a school...which is why I need to ask targeted questions like this to learn...)

Comment: Apologies! Actually, there's no prohibition against posting homework assignments as questions on Stackoverflow -- so no negative assumption here. :-) I still feel your question has a relatively straightforward solution and that you will learn more by working it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how to draw an adjustable sized grid**

[image]

First set some minimums and maximums:

```
var minX=-7;
var maxX=7;
var minY=-5;
var maxY=12;
```

Calculate the number of lines that will be in the grid

```
var vlines=maxX-minX;
var hlines=maxY-minY;
```

Calculate the width & height of each grid cell

```
var cellwidth=canvasWidth/vlines;
var cellheight=canvasHeight/hlines;
```

Now you can draw the gridlines like this:

```
function drawGrid(){

    var midYY=midY*cellheight;
    var midXX=midX*cellwidth;

    ctx.font='12px verdana';
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    ctx.globalAlpha=0.50;
    ctx.beginPath();

    // draw vertical X lines
    for(var n=1;n<vlines;n++){
        var x=parseInt(n*cellwidth);
        ctx.moveTo(x,0);
        ctx.lineTo(x,ch);
        if(n<vlines && minX+n!==0){ ctx.fillText(minX+n,x,midYY-cellheight/2); }
    }

    // draw horizontal Y lines
    for(var n=1;n<hlines;n++){
        var y=parseInt(n*cellheight);
        ctx.moveTo(0,y);
        ctx.lineTo(cw,y);
        if(n<hlines && maxY-n!==0){ ctx.fillText(maxY-n,midXX+cellwidth/2,y); }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

    // draw darker origin lines
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(midXX,0);
    ctx.lineTo(midXX,ch);
    ctx.moveTo(0,midYY);
    ctx.lineTo(cw,midYY);
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// declare mins & maxes
var minX=-7;
var maxX=7;
var minY=-5;
var maxY=12;
var midX=7;
var midY=12;
// calc # lines in grid
var vlines=maxX-minX;
var hlines=maxY-minY;
// calc cell sizes
var cellwidth=cw/vlines;
var cellheight=ch/hlines;

// context styling
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
// sharpen the lines
ctx.translate(0.50,0.50);

// go draw stuff
drawGrid();
drawPoint(-4,3);

function drawGrid(){

  var midYY=midY*cellheight;
  var midXX=midX*cellwidth;

  ctx.font='12px verdana';
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.50;
  ctx.beginPath();

  // draw vertical X lines
  for(var n=1;n<vlines;n++){
    var x=parseInt(n*cellwidth);
    ctx.moveTo(x,0);
    ctx.lineTo(x,ch);
    if(n<vlines && minX+n!==0){ ctx.fillText(minX+n,x,midYY-cellheight/2); }
  }

  // draw horizontal Y lines
  for(var n=1;n<hlines;n++){
    var y=parseInt(n*cellheight);
    ctx.moveTo(0,y);
    ctx.lineTo(cw,y);
    if(n<hlines && maxY-n!==0){ ctx.fillText(maxY-n,midXX+cellwidth/2,y); }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

  // draw darker origin lines
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(midXX,0);
  ctx.lineTo(midXX,ch);
  ctx.moveTo(0,midYY);
  ctx.lineTo(cw,midYY);
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.stroke();
}

// draw a point
function drawPoint(x,y){
  var xx=(x-minX)*cellwidth;
  var yy=(y-minY)*cellheight;
  var yy=(maxY-y)*cellheight;
  ctx.font='10px verdana';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(xx,yy,4,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillText('('+x+','+y+')',xx,yy-10);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```